# Move parent div with child div?

Tags: html, css, hover

Hey guys im pretty new to css and html and have
a pretty simple question for you.

I'm currently trying to move my parent div from out of screen  to in screen
when hovering one child of it which is located at the right side of the screen.
But somehow I cant get it to work, is it even possible to move the parent div while hovering the child div? Or what did I do wrong here?

```
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.border {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position:absolute;
  left: 97%;
}

.left {
  float:left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.right {
  float:left;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.hoverbtn {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;
}

.hoverbtn:hover + .border {
  left: 80%;
}


<div class="border">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="hoverbtn">
      <
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say out of screen to in screen, do you mean that its currently -100000000 pixels or something so that it can't be viewed?

If so then when on hover just amend that value, I could be wrong but I don't quite understand what you m,san

Comment: @Edi here you go, simple stuff

Comment: @Steve I have two more divs inside the .border div. The one on the left can be seen. If somebody hovers over it, i want the parent div to move. Just like some sidebar maybe.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks, that was exactly what I was asking for. :)

Comment: moved the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using css only you cannot affect the parents style based on a child's pseudo class (`:hover`, etc) for instance

```
.hoverbtn:hover + .border {
  left: 80%;
}
```

would style a sibling element and not the parent

There is no parent symbol like there is a child(`>`) symbol so you can't like do

```
.hoverbtn:hover < .border {
  left: 80%;
}
```

Although people have requested that there be a parent symbol like `<` or pseudo class like `:parent`

So you need to use javascript to accomplish this.